# App in cypress redirects, outside does not

Tags: javascript, redirect, cypress, e2e-testing, e2e

I am trying to write end to end tests for this application with Cypress: `https://app.gotphoto.com/admin/auth/login`

When I visit the above url from my browswer, a login form is showing, as expected.

When I visit the above url through Cypress:

- cypress first navigates to `https://app.gotphoto.com/admin/auth/login`
- immediately afterwards I am redirected to `https://app.gotphoto.com/__/` and the login form is not showing

These are two screenshots from inside Cypress:

[image]
[image]

My question is: why is there a difference between how it runs in my browser and how it runs in Cypress / Cypress's browswer?

The browswer I am using is Chrome 89, both when running with and without Cypress.

The entirety of the test I am running is this:

```
describe('login screen', () => {
  it('logs in', () => {
    cy.visit('/admin/auth/login');
  });
});
```

with a cypress.json:

```
{
  "baseUrl": "https://app.gotphoto.com"
}
```

I created a [repo](https://gitlab.com/handris/cypress-so-question) with the above configuration so it's simple to reproduce.

Comment: got reproduced on my machine the same behavior, found relevant issue FYI https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4131

Comment: @EvgeniiBazhanov thank you for linking the issue, unfortunately I found no fix for my problem there

Answer (score 3):

The `/__/` portion of `https://app.gotphoto.com/__/` is called the **clientRoute** and is an internal configuration item in Cypress.

You can turn it off in your `cypress.json` configuration file

```js
{
  ...
  "clientRoute": "/"
}
```

This effectively keeps your original url and allows the page to load properly.

```js
cy.visit('https://app.gotphoto.com/admin/auth/login')
cy.get('input#username', { timeout: 10000 }).type('admin') // long timeout
                                                           // wait for page to load
cy.get('input#password').type('password')

cy.intercept('POST', 'api.getphoto.io/v4/auth/login/user').as('user')
cy.contains('button', 'Submit').click()

cy.wait('@user').then(interception => {
  // incorrect credentials
  expect(interception.response.body.detail).to.eq('Login failed!')
})
```

I'm not sure of any bad side effects of changing `clientRoute`, will post more information if I find it.

Answer (score 1):

[An example of logging in](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/944#issuecomment-788373384). Ultimately this is a bit of a hacky solution as it fails on the very first try; however, it works on any subsequent attempt.

Add the following to your **`command.js`**

```
// -- Visit multiple domains in one test
Cypress.Commands.add('forceVisit', url => {
  cy.window().then(win => {
    return win.open(url, '_self');
  });
});
```

**`login.spec.js`**

```
describe('login screen', () => {
  it('logs in', {
    retries: {
      runMode: 1,
      openMode: 1
    }
  }, () => {
    cy.forceVisit('https://app.gotphoto.com/admin/auth/login');
    cy.get('#username').should('exist');
  });
});
```

**Screenshot**:
[image]

Comment: Can you please review for the bounty?

Answer (score 0):

That redirect to `__/` sounds familiar to an issue I stumbled upon some time ago. I found this comment in one of Cypress' [issues](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6749#issuecomment-631932833) quite helpful.

So did you already try to use the configuration option `experimentalSourceRewriting`? In your `cypress.json`, it may look like this:

```
{
    "baseUrl": "https://app.gotphoto.com"
    "experimentalSourceRewriting": true
}
```

As it's labelled [experimental](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/experiments.html#Configuration), I'd recommend testing it carefully but maybe it helps a bit. I hope for the best!

Answer (score 0):

> why is there a difference between how it runs in my browser and how it runs in Cypress / Cypress's browser?

Your normal browser waits for the XHR requests to be completed and renders the final output created by whatever js magic you have written in there but `cy.visit` is not supposed to wait for those XHR / AJAX requests inside. It gets 200 in response and moves ahead. If you add a cypress command next to `cy.visit`, something like `cy.get('h1')`, you will notice that this command runs instantly after `cy.visit`, and after that, your XHR requests are resolved.

One work around here can be to use `cy.intercept`, for example (Cypress 6.8.0, Chrome 89):

```
describe("login screen", () => {
  it("logs in", () => {
    cy.intercept({
      method: "GET",
      url: "admin/version/master/index.html"
    }).as("indexHTML"); // Similarly add other internal xhr requests

    cy.visit("/admin/auth/login");

    cy.wait("@indexHTML").then(interception => {
      expect(interception.response.statusCode).to.be.eq(200);
    });
  });
});
```

Output: [image]
It basically waits for your internal XHR requests to finish and allows you to play with the request and responses once they are resolved.

This issue will help you debug further: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4383

Also, this `/__/` has no hand in rendering the blank page IMO.

Comment: Usually you can achieve the same effect by `cy.get()` an element on the loaded page, with a suitable timeout if the page load is slow. Unfortunately no amount of waiting is fixing this problem.

Comment: I tried waiting, does not resolve the issue. I guess they will have to use something specific to the framework they are using. For example, for react cypress has https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/tree/master/npm/react

Comment: Indeed, `cy.wait("@indexHTML")` is waiting, but does not work.